# "Non riesco a camminare dritta" versus "non riesco a camminare dritto"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, difference, gender, phrase-choice

When uttered by a woman, which of the following sentences is correct?

> Non riesco a camminare dritta.

> Non riesco a camminare dritto.

My feeling is that, since *dritto* is the way of walking (in a straight line), that is what should be used, not *dritta*.

Comment: I'm often surprised at your questions. I suppose you always try to ask what a learner of Italian might wonder at. If so, I must congratulate you because you are really good at pointing out little things which a native would overlook as they are instinctively obvious.

Comment: @Paola I wish I had more interesting questions for learners of Italian.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Non riesco a camminare *dritta*

significa che non sta con la schiena dritta, si tratta di un predicativo del soggetto e l'aggettivo si concorda in genere e numero col soggetto, come sempre.

> Non riesco a camminare *dritto*

significa invece che non riesce a camminare tenendo una direzione che non si curvi. Qui "dritto" è un avverbio di modo, non modificabile.

Comment: non è un predicato nominale,`dritta` è un complemento predicativo del soggetto ( si assume che il soggetto sia femmina)